# Remove Junk and Line breakers in file

Tags: files

I am generating file from Informatica with delimiter " \007 " ,
But i am getting line breakers in other columns as well.

I  am not sure what type of line breakers i will get and not sure in which column i will get.

I need to remove all the line breakers i am getting in the file.

Note: i even have a Chinese data coming from source and i dont want to remove them.

can some one please help me in it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To remove all the line breaks in a file, you can use `sed 's/\r//g' /path/to/inputfile > /path/to/outputfile` or, if you don't care to preserve the original, `sed --in-place`.